# What will be the output of the given code and why?

Tags: javascript

How 'this' keyword works with closure?

```js
var a = 1000;
var b = 2000;

var obj2 = {
  a: 100,
  b: 200,
  sum: function(callback) {
    callback();
  },
  sum1: function() {
    console.log("a: " + this.a);
    console.log(this.a + this.b);
  }
};

var obj1 = {
  a: 10,
  b: 20,
  callSum: function() {
    obj2.sum(obj2.sum1);
  }
};

obj1.callSum();
```

Comment: Just copy/paste that into the javascript window of jsfiddle.net and you can run/play with it all you like. Your browsers console is where the answer will be so push F12 button to see it in your browser. https://jsfiddle.net/tgxoza2s/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: This question is both too generic and too specific. You can test that code yourself and see what happens with it, and you can read a whole tutorial on how closures work for the details.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `obj2.sum1` function is passed by reference and not being called as a member of the object, `this` is the global scope and not `obj2`.

A simpler example:

```
var a = "global"
var obj = {
  a: "object",
  f: function() { console.log(this.a) }
}
obj.f();    // object
var func_ref = obj.f;
func_ref(); // global
```

The same function is being executed in both cases. But writing `obj.f()` implies the binding of the context: `this = obj`